# Optimal way to store data from Pandas to Snowflake

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The dataframe is huge (7-8 million rows). Tried to_sql with chunksize = 5000 but it never finished.

Using,

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL

df.to_sql(snowflake_table , engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, index_label=None, chunksize=20000)
```

What are other optimal solutions for storing data into SF from Pandas DF? Or what am I doing wrong here? The DF is usually of size 7-10 million rows.

Comment: maybe try storing in NoSQL DB if possible. Should work better than SQL for that size.

Comment: That is not an option, unfortunately, storing to NoSQL DB

Comment: Not very familiar (at all) with Snowflake, but [COPY INTO](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) seems like a tool for the job. Save the dataframe in some (semi) structured format in a suitable staged location and copy it over.

Comment: I am considering that option as well. Converting to CSV and use copy into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal way that ilja-everila pointed out is “copy into...” as SF required the csv to be staged on cloud before transformation I was hesitant to do it but it seems like that is the only option given that the performance is in 5-10 minutes for 6.5million records.

Answer (score 2):

The least painful way I can imagine is to dump the file to `S3` and have [Snowpipe](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe.html) load it into Snowflake automatically. With that set up you don't have to execute any copy command or make any Snowflake calls at all.

Refer to Snowflake documentation for details on how to set up [Snowpipe for S3](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html). In short you need to create a stage, a target table, a file format (I guess you already have these things in place though) and a pipe. Then set up SQS notifications for your bucket that the pipe will listen to.

[Snowflake suggests](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.html) having files sized around 10-100 MB, so it is likely a good idea to split the file.

```
# set up credentials (s3fs is built on BOTO hence this is AWS specific)
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key=key, secret=secret)

# number of files to split into
n_chunks = 2

# loop over dataframe and dump chunk by chunk to S3
# (you likely want to expand file naming logic to avoid overwriting existing files)
for f_name, chunks in enumerate(np.array_split(np.arange(df.shape[0]), n_chunks)):
    bytes_to_write = df.iloc[chunks].to_csv(index=False).encode()
    with fs.open('s3://mybucket/test/dummy_{}.csv'.format(f_name), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(bytes_to_write)
```

For reference I tried this with a 7M row dataframe splitted into 5 files of around 40 MB. It took around 3 minutes and 40 seconds from starting splitting the dataframe until all rows had arrived in Snowflake.

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake provides [the `write_pandas` and `pd_writer` helper functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html#writing-data-from-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-snowflake-database) to manage that:

```py
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer

df.to_sql(snowflake_table, engine, index=False, method=pd_writer)
#                                                      ^ here
```

The `pd_writer()` function uses `write_pandas()`:

> write_pandas(): Writes a Pandas DataFrame to a table in a Snowflake database
>
> To write the data to the table, the function saves the data to Parquet files, uses the PUT command to upload these files to a temporary stage, and uses the COPY INTO  command to copy the data from the files to the table.

Answer (score 0):

for using SQLAlchemy, could you also add, in the connection parameter, the `paramstyle=qmark` that binds data.  This is also referenced here:  https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/37#issuecomment-365503841

After this change, if you feel appropriate, it may be good idea to do the performance comparison between the SQLAlchemy approach and bulk load approach of writing the large DF to files and use COPY INTO to load the files into Snowflake table.

Comment: Seeling Cheung. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it did not improve anything in terms of performance and the query kept running well over 45 minutes and then I cancelled it since csv to SF transfer takes less than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

pandas does an 'insert into ...' with multiple values behind the scene. Snowflake has a restriction up to 16384 records on ingestion. Please change your chunksize=16384.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLAlchemy you can try setting the parameter `method='multi'`

```
df.to_sql('table_name',
          con=con,
          index=False,
          if_exists='append',
          schema=schema,
          method='multi',
          chunksize=10000)
```